# C# What is this initialization doing if it doesn't have the 'new'?

Tags: c#, initialization

I'm missing what/how this even compiles, and what does it try to do:

```
// throws null reference exception on 'get' for C1:
var c2 = new Class2 { C1 = { Value = "stg" } };

public class Class1
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

class Class2
{
    public Class1 C1 { get; set; }
}
```

It's obvious that the initialization should include the "new":

```
var c2 = new Class2 { C1 = new Class1 { Value = "stg" } };
```

but how is this compiling even without the "new", and what is it trying to do?

Comment: Compiler converts `var c2 = new Class2 { C1 = { Value = "stg" } };` into `Class2 c2 = new Class2(); c2.C1.Value = "stg";` and here, on `c2.C1.Value = "stg";` we have the exception thrown

Comment: *It's obvious that the initialization should include the "new"* - you can suggest it to the compiler team if you think it's a deficit. You don't need types any more, if the compiler can see it somewhere else - `Class2 c2 = new() { C1 =  new() { Value = "stg" } };` - google "target typed creation"

Comment: *how is this compiling* - compilation never results in NullReferenceException; that's a runtime thing

Comment: @CaiusJard - I get what you're saying and I would be ok if it required only the `new()` and without the type name, but it's not even asking for that - it's not trying to create it, it's initializing the properties of the class without creating it - but, if you try that as a separate statement that wouldn't compile (i.e. just putting `C1 = { Value = "stg" }` fails to compile, as I would expect the original would've as well).

Comment: *if you try that as a separate statement that wouldn't compile* - because it's not supported. We can't really answer your question, because you're effectively asking "why did microsoft decide to implement a syntax that allows you to set properties of classes during an init when there isn't a `new` first?" - Dmitry's given the only answer reasonable there - "because they did, because the new might be done somewhere else". We can't speak to what anyone on the compiler design team was thinking when they had the meeting that discussed implementing this

Comment: Have a play with https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJabgdmQb2QEhjYZCkiriiB6W9AFwAsAnAewHcBndAOwCuAGyHpWAUwBm4iXwDG49OIAeCgA6MAluz7od6AOQBzcYwPpJ7VugDCcEMnRPnTm0ICG3bjHRyfAXn5xTgAKAEp0fFs4dECnKIA1dyEBRUCAIm5GI3T0AF98gG5kGjdPb18MQL5g8Mjo2KDQiMTk1MbM7NyCvOLKEiRiPOISlAwsMq9EJAoXNGwABnQklMUok0ZC9G5TLeHKeag4JZXUn3Xd7cv9/eQJjy8YAkdnecnuGLt6ja2dzfzkDcgA===

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construction

```
var c2 = new Class2 { C1 = { Value = "stg" } };
```

is a *syntactic sugar* which is unfurled into

```
Class c2 = new Class2();

c2.C1.Value = "stg"; // <- Here we have the exception thrown
```

It's not *evident* for compiler, that `C1` is `null` (`C1` can well be created in the constructor) that's why the code compiles.

**Edit:** Why compiler allow `C1 = { Value = "stg" }`? It's *convenient* (syntactic sugar is for our convenience), imagine:

```
public class Class1 {
  public string Value { get; set; }
}

class Class2 {
  // Suppose, that in 99% cases we want C1 with Value == "abc"
  // But only when Class1 instance is a property C1 of Class2
  public Class1 C1 { get; set; } = new Class1() { Value = "abc" };
}

...

// however, in our particular case we should use "stg":
var c2 = new Class2 { C1 = { Value = "stg" } };

// for some reason I recreate C1 (note "new"):
var otherC2 = new Class2 { C1 = new Class1 { Value = "stg" } };
```

Comment: Ok, makes sense, but why did it accept `C1 = { Value = "stg" }` as a valid statement?

Comment: @veljkoz: it's convenient (syntactic sugar is for our convenience) to be able to set inner properties as well. I've edited the answer